# I want a query to get data from a table where value are more then 1 time

Tags: sql

I have a table where pincode value are different value. I want a query to all data where pincode value appears more then 1 time.

Comment: Can you please share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for that data?

Answer (score 0):

Do it with grouping:

```
select pincode, count(*)
from TableName
group by pincode
having count(*) > 1
```